# Gigabyte B360N BIOS flash failed, can't boot from backup

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, desktop-computer, computer-building

I built a Gigabyte B360N WiFi-based computer the other day. It came up fine into BIOS, and then I went to install Debian on it. I had to enable CSM to get it to boot from the USB stick on which I had the Live installer. But no matter what I tried, I couldn't get it to recognize the m.2 SSD card installed as a viable destination for the installation.

After much googling, I decided to update the BIOS. It had version F1, and I updated to version F10. There was no documentation to be found on how to use the built-in Q-Flash tools, so I did my best. It offered a choice between "fast" and "intact" installs. Google was of little help here, but I chose the "intact" install.

I let that run for a while, and it was progressing along, then the machine started beeping. It was basically in a reboot loop, with 5 beeps each time. Nothing ever appears on the screen.

I've tried everything I can find to get it to load the backup BIOS, to no avail: press-and hold power button; press-and-hold power and reset buttons; short pins 1 & 6 on main BIOS chip while applying power; nothing has any effect.

5 beeps is supposedly a problem with the real-time clock. I've tried disconnecting the CMOS battery and clearing the CMOS, also no effect.

I'm about ready to take it back to Fry's to ask for a replacement, but what a pain. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem using a single 16 GB RAM module. Pulled the module out and tried to start without the module and it was giving 5 long beeps again. Reinserted the module again in slot 2 and was sure that it clicked well in place in both sides of the socket. After that the problem was solved. Might just have been that the RAM module is tricky to get installed in the socket. You have to click it down in one side first, then in the other side and then again in the first side.

Comment: Yeah, I checked all of that stuff. Never figured it out, ended up exchanging the board.